# Expend vs. Spend: is my understanding of the semantic difference between "Expend" and "Spend" correct?

Tags: differences, vocabulary, semantics

I, sort of, tried to handpick the best resources and dictionaries for the semantic comparison/distinction of these two words. From those, I will share the definitions by the dictionaries I mainly tend to use.

### Cambridge Dictionary

[defines](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/expend) Expend, as:

> *Verb* [T]: to use or spend time, effort, or money.

[defines](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spend) Spend, as:

> *Verb* [I or T]: to give money as a payment for something:

### Collins Dictionary

[defines](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/expend) Expend as:

> *Verb*: To expend something, especially energy, time, or money, means to use it or spend it.

[defines](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/spend) Spend as:

> *Verb*: When you spend money, you pay money for things that you want.

Is my understand correct, that:

**Expend** serves a bit more generic purpose in the cases, where we want to apply semantics of the *Consuming some finite resource*, be it a money, energy, fuel, or etc.

whilst

**Spend** defines exclusively the meaning of *Spending money for something*?

Comment: You should read the full definition; Cambridge gives 3 definitions for "spend" as a verb (headed MONEY, TIME, and FORCE), and you only quote the first.

Comment: Sometimes, adding *-able* as a suffix can provide a clue. Consider *spendable* versus *expendable*.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, your understanding of the two verbs is correct. *Expend* is, as you point out, more generic than *spend*.

However, someone can *spend* more than just money.

> I enjoy *spending* time with my friend Lisa. [The time period could be minutes, hours, or even days.]

> I *spend* most of my afternoons reading. [Here, "most of my afternoons" comprises *both* the majority of the afternoons in a week's time (i.e., at least four out of seven) *and* perhaps the majority of hours in each of those afternoons (e.g., three or four hours within the time frame of noon to 5 PM).

Finally, if a person is totally exhausted, with absolutely no more energy to continue doing what he or she has been doing, you could describe that person as *spent*.

> After having run six miles, Fred was completely spent.